# How we embed google analytics chart from google analytic with angular 4?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, chart.js

I want to display chart from google analytics to my website using angular 4, please help he how to do it.

Comment: Embed it the same way you would in a static HTML page - otherwise, what have you tried, share some code for suggestions

Comment: @viperguynaz I don't now how to do it, i just search to find a package on npm can resolve my problem but nothing

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I fould this website "https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/"  and it show me how to embed api, It working but i'm confuse how we force the access google analytics on the first time

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, GA doesn't support embeddable charts.  However, Google Data Studio is free, easily connects to GA, and does support embeddable charts.